# Tests are no longer executed through Visual Studio 2010 after Visual Studio 11 beta was installed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, testing, visual-studio-2012

I have created many TestProjects with `Visual-Studio-2010 Ultimate`. All tests were executed successfully (they were simple unit tests). Now I installed `Visual-Studio-11 beta` and I realized that they are not executed through `VS-2010`. I also tried it through MSTest (2010) from command line without success. The test execution seems to start (and never ends) but the tests are not executed without reporting any error. Through `VS-11` everything works fine.

Has anyone the same issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you checked this: [MSTest not working after installing vs11 next to vs10](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/728659/mstest-not-working-after-installing-vs11-next-to-vs10)

To paraphrase the official answer from Microsoft in the above link:

> This is a known issue with Visual Studio 2010 which got fixed in 2010
>   SP1

Get SP1 [from here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23691).

Comment: It probably got deleted since you just wrote `Have you checked this` and a link. There are a lot of users who just google and link to other pages to try to get rep without really knowing what they answer. A brief description shows that you have understood the question and that the link really is relevant.

Comment: Great, after being on SO for 3 1/2 years, I'm now classified as a drive by noob. That certainly encourage me to provide help and answers... ;)

Comment: I installed SP1 and the problem was solved. Thank you for posting your answer again :).

Answer (score 2):

I think this because the lack of SP1 of TFS 2010