# Add service reference is not working in VS 2010 when installing VS 2012 RC

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, web-services, visual-studio-2012

Add reference is failing on VS 2010 when I have installed VS 2012 RC. Why?

Comment: Thats why they always say to put beta stuff not on a product machine.. I had the same problem with the silverlight 5 rc too

Comment: Many things don't work through VS 2010 when you install the VS 2012. I had [some same issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758204/tests-are-no-longer-executed-through-visual-studio-2010-after-visual-studio-11-b) which were solved when I installed the [VS2010 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691)

Comment: Are you getting a particular error message?

Comment: No, only the reference.cs file is empty!!!!!!!!

Comment: Uninstalling f******* vs 2012, donnnnnnt ever install it on  a production machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall vs 2012, vs 2010 will give you "Unknown error", a small error message, repair vs 2010 (re-install it), and it will be OK!

[Visual Studio 2012 Error Reference.svcmap throwing Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112960/visual-studio-2012-error-reference-svcmap-throwing-error/)