# Unable to run unit/webperformance/load test remotely after installing Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, load-testing

After installing Visual Studio 2012 for testing, I can not run tests remotely (using remote test controller) from Visual Studio 2010. I start test from Visual Studio 2010 because our dev team have not migrated yet, and because our test rig is also still using VS 2010 Test Agents & Controller (2010 & 2012 version are incompatible)

The run is still pending.
[image: pending]

After enabling Logs on Test Controller, I have this message (also in EventLog)

```
E, 1360, 4, 2012/10/04, 15:40:02.080, FR-VMRD-CTRL\QTController.exe, ControllerSpooledJob.AddMessage: Failed calling event listener 
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.RemoteObjectContainer`1[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Controller.IControllerEvents]: System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Le serveur a rencontré une erreur interne. Pour plus d'informations, désactivez customErrors dans le fichier .config du serveur.

    Server stack trace: 

    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Controller.IControllerEvents.ControllerEvent(TestMessage report)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Controller.ControllerSpooledJob.<>c__DisplayClass6.<AddMessage>b__3(IControllerEvents eventListener)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.RemoteObjectContainer`1.InvokeAsRemoteUser(Action`1 invoke)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Controller.ControllerSpooledJob.AddMessage(TestMessage message)
```

The Test Rig is unchanged and there are no errors on another machine without VS2012.

Is there any way to solve this ?

**UPDATE**

W, 2328, 6, 2012/12/19, 18:02:24.287, FR-VMRD-CTRL\QTController.exe, EqtException: Execution object for run 90d0339e-5dea-4614-97bd-9f7530eea00c was not found
W, 2328, 6, 2012/12/19, 18:02:24.287, FR-VMRD-CTRL\QTController.exe, ControllerObject: DisconnectTestRun: Could not find execution object for run 90d0339e-5dea-4614-97bd-9f7530eea00c
W, 2328, 6, 2012/12/19, 18:02:24.303, FR-VMRD-CTRL\QTController.exe, EqtException: Execution object for run 7ecf5dc9-d7ce-4203-ad28-c59925ea5ffb was not found
W, 2328, 6, 2012/12/19, 18:02:24.303, FR-VMRD-CTRL\QTController.exe, ControllerObject: DisconnectTestRun: Could not find execution object for run 7ecf5dc9-d7ce-4203-ad28-c59925ea5ffb
E, 2328, 10, 2012/12/19, 18:02:41.893, FR-VMRD-CTRL\QTController.exe, ControllerExecution: Cannot reach event listener for run 358406f9-2bcd-4cc7-887e-ea50fce18a1e
E, 2328, 10, 2012/12/19, 18:02:41.893, FR-VMRD-CTRL\QTController.exe, ControllerExecution: Exception: System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Le serveur a rencontré une erreur interne. Pour plus d'informations, désactivez customErrors dans le fichier .config du serveur.

Server stack trace:

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Controller.IControllerEvents.ControllerEvent(TestMessage report)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Controller.ControllerExecution.<>c__DisplayClass1d.b__19(IControllerEvents eventListener)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.RemoteObjectContainer`1.InvokeAsRemoteUser(Action`1 invoke)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Controller.ControllerExecution.CallListeners(TestMessage testMessage)
W, 2328, 7, 2012/12/19, 18:02:41.893, FR-VMRD-CTRL\QTController.exe, DeploymentQueue: File copy canceled for file C:\Users\load.test.BE-AD\AppData\Local\VSEQT\QTController\358406f9-2bcd-4cc7-887e-ea50fce18a1e\Deployment\calculatorservice.test.dll
W, 2328, 7, 2012/12/19, 18:02:41.893, FR-VMRD-CTRL\QTController.exe, EqtException: File copy canceled.
E, 2328, 7, 2012/12/19, 18:02:41.909, FR-VMRD-CTRL\QTController.exe, DeploymentQueue.DeploymentQueueThread: Failed to perform deployment. Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Exceptions.EqtException: File copy canceled.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.DeploymentQueue.CopyFile(String agentName, String remoteFileName, String localFileName, RemoteObjectContainer`1 qtFileContainer)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.DeploymentQueue.CopyFiles(DeploymentJob job)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.DeploymentQueue.DeploymentQueueThread()
E, 2328, 7, 2012/12/19, 18:02:41.909, FR-VMRD-CTRL\QTController.exe, FileCopyComplete: Deployment exception occurred: File copy canceled.

Comment: [SO: Tests are no longer executed through Visual Studio 2010 after Visual Studio 2012 beta was installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758204/tests-are-no-longer-executed-through-visual-studio-2010-after-visual-studio-11-b)

Answer (score 1):

Are you on VS 2010 or VS 2010 SP1 ? Please install [VS 2010 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691) and try this again.

If you are using a mixed environment please have a look at [this set of additional fixes on top of SP1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2736182) too

Comment: Could I request you to enable the mstest logs using mstest.exe.config and then try to execute the tests again. The logs should provide me with some more help

Comment: Do you really need spooling enabled? Could you turn it off and see if this "hides" the issue? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.common.knownexecutionappkeys.controllerjobspooling(v=vs.80).aspx